# Implement NHibernate in .Net 2.0-project

Tags: .net, nhibernate

I have a project based on .Net 2.0 and have to implement NHibernate.

What about compatibility?

Can I use any NHibernate version?

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using .Net 2.0 use NHibernate 2.1.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHibernate#History